# can not call static method from class, show type error: method is not function javascripts

Tags: javascript, node.js

I use visual code to code file javascript:
When I call `XL_LUU_TRU.Doc_Cua_hang()` and it has issue:

> Type error: XL_LUU_TRU.Doc_Cua_hang() is not funtion

Please help me fix it
Thanks

My code for calss `XL_LUU_TRU.js` is:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Duong_dan_Thu_muc_Du_lieu = "./Du_lieu";
const Duong_dan_Thu_muc_Cua_hang = Duong_dan_Thu_muc_Du_lieu +"/Cua_hang"
const urlFolder =  Duong_dan_Thu_muc_Du_lieu+"/Tivi"
class XL_LUU_TRU{      
    static Doc_Cua_hang(){
        var Ds_Store ={}
        const Duong_dan = Duong_dan_Thu_muc_Cua_hang+"/Cua_hang.json"
        var Chuoi_Json = fs.readFileSync(Duong_dan)
        Ds_Store = JSON.parse(Chuoi_Json);
        return Ds_Store;
    }
    static Doc_DS_TV(){
        var DS_TV = [];
        var Danh_sach_Ten_Tap_Tin =fs.readdirSync(urlFolder)
        Danh_sach_Ten_Tap_Tin.forEach(Ten_Tap_tin=>{
            var urlFile = urlFolder +'/'+Ten_Tap_tin;           
            var Chuoi_Json_TV = fs.readFileSync(urlFile,'utf8');
            var DsachTv = JSON.parse(Chuoi_Json_TV);
            DS_TV.push(DsachTv);

        })
        return DS_TV;
    }
}
```

My code for main.js:

```
 const XL_LUU_TRU = require('./Xu_ly/XL_LUU_TRU.js')
var Danh_sach_Cua_hang = XL_LUU_TRU.Doc_Cua_hang();
console.log(Danh_sach_Cua_hang);
var Danh_sach_TV = XL_LUU_TRU.Doc_DS_TV();
console.log(Danh_sach_TV);
```

Comment: Why are you creating a `class` with only static methods at all? Don't use the `class` syntax when you don't plan on instantiating objects - just use an object literal instead.

Answer (score 0):

In the first file you should `export` the class:

```
exports.XL_LUU_TRU = XL_LUU_TRU
```

if you want to be able to use it outside.

Then in the second file when you require it do:

```
const XL_LUU_TRU = require('./Xu_ly/XL_LUU_TRU').XL_LUU_TRU;
```

Comment: It has other issue: ReferenceError: XL_LUU_TRU is not defined

Comment: if you'll put all the code in one file (without needing to `export` and `require`) it will work.

Comment: Thank for your support. But example require  seperate to 2 file: 1 file is XL_LUU_TRU and another file to call XL_LUU_TRU and use it. Please help me

Comment: @PhanThành sure thing. Again, this is a matter of how you expose elements in your module "to the rest of the world" and also how you import (require) it.'